# Using string variable as the Text connection

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

I am trying to write a script that loops through all the text files in a single directory and import them into Excel worksheet. They are all the same format and file type (.txt).

I have the groundwork in place for the script to successfully loop through all the files, setting the full path of each file in a string variable called `FullConnection`.

I know the variable is correctly setting the full path of the file because I am showing it in a message box right before where the import should happen.

**My question is this**:

> why does the below code not work for passing in the variable as the connection name?

I'm sure it's something silly I'm doing wrong but can't seem to work it out. Hardcoding a single filepath works fine, so I know it's just the connection variable that is giving me issues.

I've seen the [MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb178808(v=office.12).aspx) on this topic  but they don't show how to set a variable as the connection string, only hardcoding the actual path of the text file. Any help is appreciated!

```
MsgBox fullConnection

'Start importing current file into Excel:
With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:="TEXT;<fullConnection>", Destination:=Range("$A$1") _
    )
    .Name = fullConnection
    .FieldNames = True
    .RowNumbers = False
    .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
    .PreserveFormatting = True
    .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
    .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
    .SavePassword = False
    .SaveData = True
    .AdjustColumnWidth = True
    .RefreshPeriod = 0
    .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
    .TextFilePlatform = 437
    .TextFileStartRow = 4
    .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
    .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
    .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
    .TextFileTabDelimiter = True
    .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
    .TextFileCommaDelimiter = False
    .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
    .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
    .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
    '.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
End With
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've enveloped the path variable into the quoted string. You need to concatenate the path variable onto the right end of that quoted string.

```
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:="TEXT;" & fullConnection, Destination:=Range("$A$1") _
)
...
```

I've also added a [WorkSheets.Add method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838966.aspx) that should guarantee that each text file is brought into a new worksheet.

Comment: That worked perfectly--thanks so much! I greatly appreciate the help.